# How to send a sms message through broadcast receiver class

Tags: android, sms

Whats up guys,
Is it possible to create a class that sends a text message inside the same class as the broadcast Receiver?? 
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, to send the sms you just need the intent to send the sms like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse(“phonenumber”));
intent.putExtra(“sms_body”, body);
intent.putExtra(“compose_mode”, true);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

So for this code you need the `Context` object.

Comment: So does this send it automatically??? thats what i want... Thanks for offering your help by the way.